# Ember.js data associations not saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say I have 2 models:

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
   street: DS.attr('string'),
   person: DS.belongsTo('App.Person')
})

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  addresses: DS.hasMany('App.Address')
})
```

Now I create a person

```
App.person = App.Person.createRecord({name: 'Bill'});
App.store.commit();
```

If I try to add an address to the person like this

```
address = App.Address.createRecord({street: '123 Fake Street'});
App.person.get('addresses').pushObject(address);
```

and commit the transaction

```
App.store.commit();
```

The new address will be saved however the person object will not be recognized as changed;
even though the list of ids has gone from

```
{
  ...
  "addresses": []
}
```

to

```
{
  ...
  "addresses": [3]
}
```

Is there a way to let ember-data know that my person object has been changed and it needs
to be saved?

Edit:
[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/CamShaft/HBm4j/) is a jsfiddle illustrating the problem.

Comment: I don't mind where the error is, as console displays expected results... Any up to date status about your issue? Maybe you where using an old ember-data revision? Are you still encountering this problem?

Answer (score 1):

As of now (ember-data revision 4) there is no way to do this. The object is only persisted on the belongsTo side since it has the foreign key, so if you set the value in the belongs to side of the relation it should persist. The next version of ember data should address this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The work around I've found for this would be to just manually add the id like:

```
App.Address = DS.Model.extend({
   street: DS.attr('string'),
   personID: DS.attr('string'),
   person: DS.belongsTo('App.Person')
})
```

then when you send your data, set the personId field and it'll mimic what the person field seems like it should send.

Answer (score 1):

How about writing your own serializer for this , see http://ember-website.thomasboyt.com/api/data/modules/data-serializer.html